# Kann man »erinnern« (ohne »an«) auch intransitiv verwenden?

Tags: phrase, reflexive

Ich höre seit einiger Zeit immer wieder Sätze wie

> Ich erinnere, dass das Brot früher anders geschmeckt hat.

... und es rollen sich mir die Zehennägel hoch!

Für mich fühlt sich das an wie ein ganz kruder Anglizismus (vgl. "to remember"), aber eine befreundete Lektorin hat mir versichert, dass die [intransitive](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitivit%C3%A4t_(Grammatik)) Form (also »ich erinnere« statt »ich erinnere mich«) in der deutschen Sprache erlaubt ist und auch schon immer erlaubt war.

Stimmt das?

Es geht mir wohlgemerkt **nicht** um »erinnern an«, also Sätze wie:

> Ich erinnere [euch] nochmals an den Abgabetermin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google Books hat jede Menge Zitate für [„ich erinnere daß“](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&hs=5U0&channel=fs&biw=1180&bih=966&tbm=bks&q=%22ich%20erinnere%20da%C3%9F%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) und [„ich erinnere wie“](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&channel=fs&biw=1180&bih=936&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&q=%22ich%20erinnere%20wie%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=), z. B.:

- Hans Ernst Kinck, *Machiavelli: seine Geschichte und seine Zeit*, **1938**:

  > **Ich erinnere, wie** wir am ersten Fastensonntag, das war der 12. Februar, heimkamen.
- *Akademie für Deutsches Recht 1933–1945, Protokolle der Ausschüsse: Ausschuß für Aktienrecht, Band 1*; Sitzungen vom **14.–20.10.1937**:

  > Das wäre eine Gelegenheit, in bezug auf das Institut der Vor- und Nacherbschaft,
  >   das ja mancher wenig freundlich ansieht – **ich erinnere, daß** wir bei der ersten
  >   Erörterung der Vor- und Nacherbschaft erwogen haben, ob man sie nicht abschaffen soll –, der Öffentlichkeit darzulegen, daß Fälle vorkommen können, in denen im Interesse der Erhaltung des Vermögens in der Familie die Festsetzung der Vor- und Nacherbschaft durch Testament geboten erscheint.
- *Stenographische Berichte über die Verhandlungen des Deutschen Reichstages*; Datum unklar, aber **vor 1903**:

  > **Ich erinnere, daß** in der Kommission von Regierungsseite ausdrücklich zugegeben wurde,
  >   daß dieses Zollsystem eine große Sachkenntniß und außerordentliche Gewissenhaftigkeit der Beamten voraussetze.
  >
  > [image]
- Constanze Esmarch an Theodor Storm, Brief vom **15.12.1845**:

  > Du hast ja doch früher nichts gegen die Stiefeln gehabt, und **ich errinere,
  >   daß** ich Dich vorigen Winter ganz verliebt machen konnte, wenn ich Dir ein
  >   kleines Stück von meinem weißen Strumpf zeigte[.]

Und so weiter, und so fort (eigentlicher Urheber nicht immer klar, Quellenangaben nach bestem Wissen und Gewissen):

> - [I]ch lege eine Sammlung mit meinen Spezialgerichten an, eine Geschenkidee: zehn persönliche Gerichte für manche bzw. für meine Fälle, in Oktavheftchen wär schön, **ich erinnere wie** eine ältere Dame ein Oktavheftchen sucht, genau wie ich es am selben Orte suchte[.] (*Fuszspuren: Füsze: Texte und Zeichen von Wien nach Berlin*, Janus-Press, 1994)
> - **Ich erinnere, wie** ich in den 60er Jahren meinen Eltern persönlich vorhielt, nicht im Widerstand während des Nationalsozialismus tätig gewesen zu sein[.] (Deutsche Gesellschaft für Psychologie, 1994)
> - **Ich erinnere, wie** schnell ich damals bereit war, die Stimme hinter der Zeitung zum festen Bestand meiner Umgebung zu zählen. (*Erzählungen seit 1945*, dtv)
> - **Ich erinnere wie** er am Frühstückstisch ass, wie ein hungeriger Mensch isst, und sie sass nur und sah ihn an; doch wenn sie von Vogelsang sprach, sprach er von Kalbssteak! (*Die Insel*, 1902)
> - Ich weiß nicht mehr, wann oder wo, aber **ich erinnere, wie** sie mit den Händen abwinkte[.] (Hanna Lévy-Hass, *Tagebuch aus Bergen-Belsen: 1944-1945*)
> - Ich werde in meiner Vermuthung bestärkt, wenn **ich erinnere, wie** Plato einst in seinem späteren Lebensalter zu der nähmlichen Ueberzeugung gelangte, daß... (*Nietzsche, Briefwechsel*, Kritische Gesamtausgabe)

Die Form ist also weder neu noch auf Norddeutschland oder Umgangssprache begrenzt. Ob das Englische hier abfärbt, ist folglich Spekulation.

Comment: Hmmm, bedeutet *"Ich erinnere, dass"* aber nicht etwas anderes als *"Ich erinnere mich, dass"*? Das erste ist *"Ich erinnere Sie daran, ..."* das zweite ist *"Mir fällt wieder ein, ..."*, oder? Beispiel 1, 2 und 4. Beispiel 3 = Norddeutschland :-)

Comment: @splattne: 1 und 2 kann man meines Erachtens so oder so lesen; bei 4 gebe ich Dir eigentlich recht... ich editiere mal ein wenig.

Comment: +1 für historische Quellen - es ist also doch nicht ausschließlich ein alberner Anglizismus, wie ich immer dachte. Hätte ich nicht gedacht!

Comment: In der Quelle von 1903 scheint das aber eher in der Bedeutung von *jmd. an etwas erinnern*.

Comment: @Pekka: man darf kognitive Verzerrung niemals unterschätzen. Wir verdächtigen das englische *remember* doch nur, weil es nunmal das Englische ist, dessen wir hier alle mächtig sind. Niemand verdächtigt das polnische *pamiętać* oder das tschechische *pamatovat* – dabei sind sie, wenn mich nicht alles täuscht, genauso transitiv und genausowenig mit dem deutschen *erinnern* verwandt wie *remember*. Und im Gegensatz zum *remember* hätten sie sich ganz bequem und in aller Ruhe über den Landweg einschleichen können.

Answer (score 13):

In Norddeutschland wird die Form mit Akkusativ, nach der du fragst, häufig verwendet.

[Duden online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erinnern) führt die Form unter "Grammatik auf"

> etwas erinnern: ich erinnere das, [ich erinnere] diesen Vorfall nicht (besonders norddeutsch)

Im Hochdeutschen ist die reflexive Form mit *an* am weitesten verbreitet. In gehobener Sprache wird schon mal der Genitiv verwendet: *Ich erinnere mich des Geschmacks.*

In Österreich hört man übrigens in der Umgangssprache auch *sich auf etwas erinnern*.

Comment: +1 und ich habe hin- und herüberlegt, bei welcher Antwort ich den Haken setze - viele gute Beispiele vs. Duden-Zitat. Letztlich hat sie dann derjenige mit weniger Rep bekommen ;-)

Comment: "ich erinnere das, diesen Vorfall nicht" - was genau soll das heißen? Anm.: Ich bin selbst Norddeutscher und habe nicht die geringste Ahnung, was mit diesem Satz ausgedrückt werden soll... Klingt für mich, als hätte da jemand ein paar Wörter vergessen oder so...

Comment: @Oliver_Giesen Ich glaube das Beispiel war alternativ gemeint: *"Ich erinnere das."* und *"Ich erinnere diesen Vorfall nicht."* - Ich (aus dem Süden) persönlich würde diese Sätze nicht so sagen.

Comment: Ah OK, das mag sein. Ich würde das übrigens auch nie so sagen. Ich gehöre bei dieser Verwendung von "erinnern" auch eher zu der Fußnägelhochrollfraktion...