# Are da-compounds like dazu always necessary even when they seem redundant?

Tags: preposition, pronoun, subordinate-clause

I am working on translating a video game into German and I am unsure whether I need to use da-compounds in certain contexts. I have sentences like

> Despite the wall's poor condition, you are still unable to pry out the bricks.

which I might translate as

> Trotz des armen Zustands der Mauer, sind Sie noch nicht dazu fähig, die Ziegelsteine herauszustemmen.

In English I would say either

> you are still unable to do that (i.e. Sie sind noch nicht dazu fähig)

or

> you are still unable to pry out the bricks (i.e. Sie sind noch nicht fähig, die Ziegelsteine herauszustemmen)

but it would certainly be redundant to say

> you are still unable to do that, to pry out the bricks

However in German I feel inclined to add "dazu" since the phrase "to be capable of something" is "zu etwas fähig sein." I am not sure if this is redundant because I am using "zu" twice.

I have seen this existing question regarding "sich an etwas erinnern": [Are “da”-compounds necessary for clauses?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/are-da-compounds-necessary-for-clauses) but that question is only about using "an" once in "daran," whereas I am asking about using "zu" twice.

Comment: “arm” is the wrong word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the verbs that have a prepositional phrase as their complement allow the da-compound (Pronominaladverb) to be left out.

Your phrase is "**zu etwas fähig sein**", so the object is a prepositional phrase with "zu".

> Ich bin **zu Großem** fähig.

Therefore, you can leave out "dazu" if you want.

> Trotz des schlechten Zustands der Mauer sind Sie noch nicht (dazu) fähig, **die Ziegelsteine herauszustemmen**.

Another example: "**sich vor etwas hüten**".

> Er hütet sich (davor), eine Straftat zu begehen.

Duden Grammar 2009 Nr.861

---

Also, *trotz* is a preposition. Your first comma is wrong.