# "Wessen erinnert er sich noch?" vs. Woran oder an wen erinnert er sich noch?"

Tags: phrase, pronoun

Ich lese [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-wer-was.html#Anchor-Formen-11481) und [hier](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Fragepronomen_wer_was) den Satz

> Wessen erinnert er sich noch?

es war eine Überraschung für mich, weil ich gelernt habe, dass das Verb "erinnern" ein Verb mit der Präpositionalergänzung "an+AKK" ist, also wäre der Satz

> Woran oder an wen erinnert er sich noch?

Meine Frage ist, der erste und zweite Satz haben identische Bedeutung?

Wenn ja, warum haben wir "wessen" in dem ersten Satz und nicht "woran" oder "an wen"?

Wenn nein, warum?

Comment: Related: [Kann man “erinnern” (ohne “an”) auch intransitiv verwenden?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1257/9551)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Erinnern* kann sowohl mit einem **Präpositionalobjekt** als auch mit dem **Genitiv** verwendet werden. Letzteres wird aber meist nur bei gehobener Ausdrucksweise genutzt. Der Genitiv wird generell in der Sprache durch die anderen beiden Fälle (v.a. den Dativ) verdrängt.

Also ja, beide Fragesätze haben die gleiche Bedeutung, unterscheiden sich aber im *Stil*.

Comment: ich kapiere, danke! Es ist wie zu sagen Z.b. "Wovon oder von wem reden Sie?" oder "Wessen reden Sie?", oder?

Comment: @mle, "Wessen reden Sie?" ist falsch

Comment: @Iris, ok, ich wusste es nicht, pardon.. Hast du bitte ein richtiges Beispiel?

Comment: @mle, das "wessen" gilt speziell für das Verb "erinnern", nicht für "reden". Außerdem kenne ich "erinnern dessen" nur aus Theaterstücken,  im Alltag würde ich immer "erinnern an"  nehmen.

Comment: Ein vergleichbares Verb ist „gedenken“, das wird noch immer ausschließlich mit dem Genitiv genutzt: „Wir gedenken des Opfers.“  Für die Zukunft ließe sich vielleicht absehen, dass auch dieses Verb mehr und mehr mit dem Dativ genutzt werden wird („Wir gedenken dem Opfer“), aber noch wird das als falsch empfunden.

Comment: Was heißt "die anderen beiden Fälle"? Es gibt 3 andere Fälle, nicht 2. Und der Genetiv ist lange totgesagt aber verschwindet nicht. Ich wäre da vorsichtiger mit Prognosen.

Comment: @userunknown es ist klar dass nicht der nominativ mit eingeschlossen sein kann! wenn dich das stört editier die antwort. unnötiger downvote

Comment: Vergiss mein nicht